# PCI (Bus) vs PCI (PCI DSS) tags. How do you encourage correct tagging?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

I'm particularly interested in questions and answers relating to PCI (bus), but I am finding many questions tagged with [pci](/questions/tagged/pci) that actually refer to [PCI DSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard).

Is there anything that can be done to encourage correct tagging? Like removing [pci](/questions/tagged/pci) and creating [pci-bus](/questions/tagged/pci-bus) and [pci-dss](/questions/tagged/pci-dss)? I see that [pci-bus](/questions/tagged/pci-bus) already exists.

Comment: Are we talking SO here? Or Super User? If the latter, this question is better for Super User's own Meta. http://meta.superuser.com/

Comment: @Bart-  have to agree. On security. SE for example, we would not have any questions about the PCI bus but many on PCI-DSS so this question is very site specific.

Comment: I do mean SO here. I search for questions related to programming PCI(e) BARs, and keep getting hits for PHP / PCI (DSS).

Comment: Given that [pci-dss] already exists, why not go through the questions tagged [pci] and retag those referring to [pci-dss] as such? There are not that many questions with the tag to begin with, so it should not be much work. And perhaps [pci] and [pci-bus] can be synonymized, or [pci] removed altogether.

Comment: There were only a few misuses of [pci] so I retagged them [pci-dss]/[pci-compliance] as appropriate, a synonym would be good.

Comment: Thanks for showing the way. @Bart : Care to turn your comment into an answer? I accept "consider replacing [pci] with [pci-bus], and edit PCI DSS questions so that they reference [pci-dss] instead of [pci]".

Comment: @KevinM Given that I can't create, nor single-handedly decide on the synonym, I won't make it an answer. Leave your question open for a while.